# Which of these patterns is better OOP design when I have separate "data" and "procedures"?

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

Let's say for example that this is my data

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }

    int Age { get; }
}

public class AmericanCitizen : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public SocialSecurityNumber SSN { get; set; }
}

public class StackOverflowPoster : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Alias { get; set; }   
}
```

meaning these are just "value bags" (like models of database rows).

And let's say I need some type of procedure that acts on different implementations.

One way is to have a method with `switch` or `if-else`, like

```
public class UniqueIdentifierPrinter : IUniqueIdentifierPrinter
{   
    public void Identity(IPerson person)
    {
        if (person is AmericanCitizen)
        {
            AmericanCitizen american = (AmericanCitizen)person;
            Console.WriteLine(american.SSN.ToString());
        }
        else if (person is StackOverflowPoster)
        {
            StackOverflowPoster SOer = (StackOverflowPoster)person;
            Console.WriteLine(SOer.Alias);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way I can think of is to put the `Identify` implementations in separate classes, like

```
public interface IPersonIdentifier<out T> where T : IPerson
{
    void Identify();    
}

public class AmericanCitizenIdentifer : IPersonIdentifier<AmericanCitizen>
{
    AmericanCitizen american;

    public AmericanCitizenIdentifer(AmericanCitizen american)
    {
        this.american = american;
    }

    public void Identify()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(american.SSN.ToString());
    }
}


public class StackOverflowPosterIdentifier : IPersonIdentifier<StackOverflowPoster>
{
    StackOverflowPoster poster;

    public StackOverflowPosterIdentifier(StackOverflowPoster american)
    {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public void Identify()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(poster.Alias);
    }
}


public static class Identifying
{
    public static void Identify(IPerson person)
    {
        IPersonIdentifier<IPerson> identifier;

        if (person is AmericanCitizen)
        {
            identifier = new AmericanCitizenIdentifer((AmericanCitizen)person);
        }
        else if (person is StackOverflowPoster)
        {
            identifier = new StackOverflowPosterIdentifier((StackOverflowPoster)person);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        identifier.Identify();
    }
}
```

So which is better, and why?

Comment: Just a comment. If you are going to use the "if X is Y then xy= (Y)X" pattern (which I'm not advocating), use the new form of C#'s "switch" statement; it almost makes for a clean implementation.

Comment: @Flydog57 Can you show me a link to that syntax?

Comment: Search for "type pattern" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#a-namepattern--pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a `GetIdentity` method to `IPerson` and implement it to return required information depending on the type. Then all you need to do is call that method.

```
interface IPerson
{
    string GetIdentity();
}

public class AmericanCitizen : IPerson
{
    public string GetIdentity() => SSN.ToString();
}

public class StackOverflowPoster : IPerson
{
    public string GetIdentity() => Alias;
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to add a read-only string property named Identity to IPerson.

Comment: I second Flydog's comment - a property seems more appropriate here.

Comment: Yeah, basically the same thing. The idea is same. Properties are methods anyways :)

Comment: @SelmanGenç yes, they are, but not semantically, and simply getting a value is the semantics of a property, not of a method :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
public interface IHaveIdentity {
    string Identity { get; }
}

public class AmericanCitizen : IPerson, IHaveIdentity {
    //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is typical structural approach. It is inconsistent with second SOLID rule which says that classes should be opened for extension and closed for modification. In your case, every time you add new implementation of IPerson you have to modify you class. Solution which is based on generic types and polymorphism is usually much better. So your second example seems to be quite correct, but of course in more complex examples than this one provided. In such simple case, adding single property to IPerson would be absolutely enough.